# Django: Successive Queryset Filtering Stops Filtering after First Query

Tags: django, django-orm

The debug session below illustrates what I am trying to say.
I have executed this under the Django dev server, Cherrypy server and Werkzeug debugger.
Using Django 1.11.10 on Windows 10, MySQL 5.5 back end.

The function (at the end of this post) does successive filtering on a QuerySet.
I stopped execution to perform some sanity checks.
What I found is that the first filter operation worked event_values.count() == 14 but any further attempts to filter would always yield the same results.
For example, I filtered on a pk=72 and still all 14 model instances were returned.
I tried to use get(pk=72) and got a  MultipleObjectsReturned  exception.

Interestingly, when I perform the successive filtering in the Django shell, I get the results that I am supposed to get, but when I run the actual code from the shell it also has the same problem.

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
(Pdb) l
160                 event_values = event_values.filter(
161                     tsn__gte=tsn_start, tsn__lte=tsn_end)
162
163             import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
164
165  ->         if tso_start or tso_end:
166                 tso_start, tso_end = resolve_ranges(tso_start, tso_end)
167
168                 event_values = event_values.filter(
169                     tso__gte=tso_start, tso__lte=tso_end)
170
(Pdb) tsn_start
5800
(Pdb) tsn_end
6000
(Pdb) event_values.count()
14
(Pdb) event_values
<QuerySet [<ComplianceEvent: pk: 72 -- 383201 -- 2017-12-11 -- SB>, <ComplianceEvent: pk: 73 -- 383202 -- 2017-04-11 -- SB>, <ComplianceEvent: pk: 74 -- 383203 -- 2018-01-15 -- SB>, <ComplianceEvent: pk: 75 -- 383210 -- 2017-10-06 -- SB>, <ComplianceEvent: pk: 76 -- 383217 -- 2018-05-18 -- SB>, <ComplianceEvent: pk: 77 -- 383219 -- 2017-09-21 -- SB>, <ComplianceEvent: pk: 78 -- 383303 -- 2017-07-19 -- SB>, <ComplianceEvent: pk: 79 -- 383303 -- 2017-07-07 -- SB>, <ComplianceEvent: pk: 80 -- 383309 -- 2018-02-23 -- SB>, <ComplianceEvent: pk: 81 -- 383313 -- 2018-03-07 -- SB>, <ComplianceEvent: pk: 82 -- 383315 -- 2016-04-18 -- SB>, <ComplianceEvent: pk: 83 -- 383317 -- 2017-04-21 -- SB>, <ComplianceEvent: pk: 84 -- 383319 -- 2018-02-22 -- SB>, <ComplianceEvent: pk: 85 -- 383324 -- 2018-08-15 -- SB>]>
(Pdb) event_values.filter(pk=72)
<QuerySet [<ComplianceEvent: pk: 72 -- 383201 -- 2017-12-11 -- SB>, <ComplianceEvent: pk: 73 -- 383202 -- 2017-04-11 -- SB>, <ComplianceEvent: pk: 74 -- 383203 -- 2018-01-15 -- SB>, <ComplianceEvent: pk: 75 -- 383210 -- 2017-10-06 -- SB>, <ComplianceEvent: pk: 76 -- 383217 -- 2018-05-18 -- SB>, <ComplianceEvent: pk: 77 -- 383219 -- 2017-09-21 -- SB>, <ComplianceEvent: pk: 78 -- 383303 -- 2017-07-19 -- SB>, <ComplianceEvent: pk: 79 -- 383303 -- 2017-07-07 -- SB>, <ComplianceEvent: pk: 80 -- 383309 -- 2018-02-23 -- SB>, <ComplianceEvent: pk: 81 -- 383313 -- 2018-03-07 -- SB>, <ComplianceEvent: pk: 82 -- 383315 -- 2016-04-18 -- SB>, <ComplianceEvent: pk: 83 -- 383317 -- 2017-04-21 -- SB>, <ComplianceEvent: pk: 84 -- 383319 -- 2018-02-22 -- SB>, <ComplianceEvent: pk: 85 -- 383324 -- 2018-08-15 -- SB>]>
(Pdb) event_values.get(pk=72)
*** esipeht.models.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one ComplianceEvent -- it returned 14!
(Pdb) ComplianceEvent.objects.get(pk=72)
<ComplianceEvent: pk: 72 -- 383201 -- 2017-12-11 -- SB>
```

Full code:

```
def evaluate_search(criteria):
    """Execute the query and return associated engine events.

    The submitted dict:
    {
    'ac_rh_end': None,
    'ac_rh_start': None,
    'affected_parts': ['31'],
    'aircraft': [],
    'end_date': None,
    'engines': [],
    'event_source': '',
    'event_subtype': ['Compliance-SB'],
    'positions': [],
    'ref_docs': [],
    'ress': [],
    'start_date': None,
    'status': '',
    'tsn_end': 6000,
    'tsn_start': 5800,
    'tso_end': None,
    'tso_start': None
    }    

    Args:
        criteria (dict): The criteria posted by the user.

    Returns:
        The associated engine events.
    """

    ac_rh_end = criteria['ac_rh_end']
    ac_rh_start = criteria['ac_rh_start']
    end_date = criteria['end_date']
    start_date = criteria['start_date']
    event_source = criteria['event_source']
    tsn_end = criteria['tsn_end']
    tsn_start = criteria['tsn_start']
    tso_end = criteria['tso_end']
    tso_start = criteria['tso_start']
    review_status = criteria['status']

    # get ids of the form multiselects
    # note: if the criteria was not selected, the result will be an empty list
    affpart_ids = criteria['affected_parts']
    aircraft = criteria['aircraft']
    engines = criteria['engines'] 
    ref_doc_ids = criteria['ref_docs']
    res_ids = criteria['ress']
    positions = criteria['positions']

    event_subtype = criteria['event_subtype']

    # create a dictionary with all subtypes initialized to empty querysets
    events = {
        'Fitment' : FitmentEvent.objects.none(),
        'Compliance' : ComplianceEvent.objects.none(), 
        'Incident' : IncidentEvent.objects.none(),
        'RepairOverhaul' :  RepairOverhaulEvent.objects.none()
    }

    # if one or more event subtypes were selected by user
    if event_subtype:
        # determine event and event subtype
        for type_subtype in event_subtype:
            event_type, subtype = type_subtype.split('-')

            model_class = getattr(esipeht.models, event_type + 'Event')

            events[event_type] |= model_class.objects.filter(
                event_subtype=subtype
            )

    # if no subtypes selected then we want everything
    else:
        if affpart_ids:
            # Fitment events do not reference affected parts            
            events['Fitment'] = FitmentEvent.objects.none()

        else:
            events['Fitment'] = FitmentEvent.objects.all()

        events['Compliance'] = ComplianceEvent.objects.all()

        events['Incident'] = IncidentEvent.objects.all()

        events['RepairOverhaul'] = RepairOverhaulEvent.objects.all()

    results = []

    # keep track of the number of each type of event
    all_counts = {
        'Fitment' : 0,
        'Compliance' : 0,
        'Incident' : 0,
        'RepairOverhaul' : 0
    }

    # loop through the query sets (event_values) for each event type (key)
    for event_type, event_values in events.items(): 
        if event_values.count() == 0:
            continue

        if engines:
            event_values = event_values.filter(
                engine__serial_number__in=engines)

        if aircraft:
            event_values = event_values.filter(
                aircraft__tail_number__in=aircraft)

        if positions:
            event_values = event_values.filter(engine_position__in=positions)

        # a fitment event does not reference affected parts
        if affpart_ids and event_type != 'Fitment':
            event_values1 = event_values.filter(
                affected_parts__id__in=affpart_ids)

            event_values2 = event_values.filter(
                ress__affected_parts__id__in=affpart_ids)

            event_values = event_values1.union(event_values2)

        if ref_doc_ids:
            event_values = event_values.filter(
                reference_documents__id__in=ref_doc_ids)

        if res_ids:
            event_values = event_values.filter(ress__id__in=res_ids)

        if tsn_start or tsn_end:
            tsn_start, tsn_end = resolve_ranges(tsn_start, tsn_end)

            event_values = event_values.filter(
                tsn__gte=tsn_start, tsn__lte=tsn_end)

        import pdb; pdb.set_trace() 

        if tso_start or tso_end:
            tso_start, tso_end = resolve_ranges(tso_start, tso_end)

            event_values = event_values.filter(
                tso__gte=tso_start, tso__lte=tso_end)

        if ac_rh_start or ac_rh_end:
            ac_rh_start, ac_rh_end = resolve_ranges(ac_rh_start, ac_rh_end)

            event_values = event_values.filter(
                aircraft_hours__gte=ac_rh_start, aircraft_hours__lte=ac_rh_end)

        if start_date or end_date:
            start_date, end_date = resolve_ranges(start_date, end_date)

            event_values = event_values.filter(
                event_date__gte=start_date, event_date__lte=end_date)

        if event_source:
            event_values = event_values.filter(source=event_source)

        if review_status:
            event_values = event_values.filter(review_status=review_status)

        results.extend(list(event_values.distinct()))

        all_counts[event_type] += event_values.count()

    sorted_results = sorted(results, key=attrgetter('engine', 'event_date'))

    grouped_events = {}

    for event in sorted_results:
        engine = event.engine.serial_number

        if engine in grouped_events:
            grouped_events[engine].append(event)

        else:
            grouped_events[engine] = [event]

    return grouped_events, all_counts


def resolve_ranges(start, end):
    """This will determine how numeric and date ranges are filtered.
    """

    if start and end:
        # if start and end are reversed, swap them
        if end < start:
            start, end = end, start

        return start, end

    elif start:
        end = (
            datetime.date.today() if type(start) == datetime.date else 999999
        )

        return start, end

    elif end:
        start = (
            datetime.date(2009, 1, 1) if type(end) == datetime.date else 0
        )

        return start, end

    return None, None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

Replace

```
event_values = event_values1.union(event_values2)
```

with

```
event_values = (event_values1 | event_values2).distinct()
```

The union() method evaluated properly but the resulting Queryset could not be filtered any further.

I checked the docs at

[Django Queryset UNION](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#union)

Found out that this is by design:

*In addition, only LIMIT, OFFSET, COUNT(*), ORDER BY, and specifying columns (i.e. slicing, count(), order_by(), and values()/values_list()) are allowed on the resulting QuerySet.*